# Where does Reactjs Server Component hide the backend code?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am learning the latest Reactjs from Next.js and found the Server Component.

It allows me to put the code which fetch data from database directly without worry about the security issue.

I rendered the [example code](https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/fetching-data) and inspected the component where the backend code was and found no code at all.

So I'm curious where the does backend code hide? and how does this thing work?

I also searched the Server Component on React.dev and I cannot find its document.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

server component does not ship any javascript to the client. that is one of the benefits of the component. think of the server as an HTML template generator and then it ships the HTML to the browser in JSON format and the browser builds the DOM.

Backend code hides in the backend. if you want to see it on your local machine, run `npm build` and check `.next` folder:

[image]